# Between Cover and Partition

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, partitions, covering

In a *cover* problem, there is a complex shape (e.g. a polygon), and we have to find a set of simpler shapes (e.g. squares or rectangles), such that their union is exactly equal to the complex shape.

A *partition* problem is similar, but the simpler shapes must be disjoint.

I am looking into a intermediate problem: there is a complex shape, and we have to partition it into k disjoint pieces (where k is a given constant), and then cover each of the pieces with simple shapes (not necessarily disjoint).

For lack of a better name, I call it: a *k-part-cover* problem. In this terminology, the 1-part-cover problem is the usual cover problem.

I am mainly interesting in covering an axis-aligned polygon with axis-aligned squares, but other scenarios are also welcome.

The interesting questions are:

- Theoretic question: **What is the minimum number of squares required to k-part-cover a given polygon, as a function of k and the polygon properties?**
- Practical question: **How can we find the minimum k-part-covering of a given polygon?**

The theoretic question seems non-trivial even for k=2. I could solve it only when the polygon to cover is a rectangle. Suppose the rectangle has an aspect ratio of L. Then:

- When $1 \leq L <1.5$, the minimum 2-part-cover has 4 squares.
- When $1.5 \leq L <2$, the minimum 2-part-cover has 3 squares.
- When $2 \leq L$, the minimum 2-part-cover has $\lceil L \rceil$ squares.

The practical problem is probably NP-hard in the general case (it is known to be NP-hard even when k=1), but there may be approximations or solutions for specific cases, such as simply-connected or convex polygons.